# Maven dependency type ejb vs jar

Tags: maven, types, pom.xml

What is the difference between

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>groupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: An `ejb` type is generated by [maven-ejb-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/) and the intention is that this is an EJB which is used in relationship with an EE application.

Comment: @khmarbaise: And what if I use jar? Isn't this possible for an EE application as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<type>ejb</type>` is needed when your artifact `artifactId` has EJBs and you want to use them. If you don't need the EJBs in your module `<type>jar</type>` is an option.

Answer (score 2):

Maven will trigger a different lifecycle, depending on the packaging.
See [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Built-in_Lifecycle_Bindings) for a list of bundled lifecycles.

In your particular case, the difference will be that, instead of calling the `jar:jar` goal during the `package` phase when using `jar` as packaging, it will trigger the `ejb:ejb` one, capable of handling specific tasks related to an EJB module (client generation...).

Comment: And when do I have to use one or the other?

Comment: It really depends on the purpose of your module. You can see the `maven-ejb-plugin` as a specialized `maven-jar-plugin`; if you do need one of the special treatment the `maven-ejb-plugin` provides (check the plugin site - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/ -  for more info),  you'd better use the ejb packaging. If not (for instance when using EJB spec 3+), you might just use the `maven-jar-plugin`, so keep the default packaging.

Comment: `maven-ejb-plugin` will have to be used if you need some specific 'EJB' capabilities for your Maven module, such as generating an EJB client, specifying the EJB version to use... (see https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: AFAIK, this does not answer the question (ejb type of a dependency). This answer is more about the ejb packaging

Comment: @Tome The question  talks of dependency type and not project type

Answer (score 0):

As the ejb is [the main artifact generated by the maven-ejb-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/ejb-mojo.html) and since it's a JAR artifact, it doesn't really matter if you're you using the ejb type or use the (default) jar type when specifying a dependency, AFAIK. (Similar to OSGi bundles, which sometimes also are created with the bundle packaging, but are just JAR files).

If you want to add a dependency to a secondary artifact (e.g. ejb-client, test-jar) or if the dependency has a different file extension, then you have to [specify the type](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/ejb-client-dependency.html) or the [classifier](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html).

The documentation seems to prefer [to use the ejb type](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ejb-plugin/examples/ejb-client-dependency.html), but it also produces some noise and is sometimes slightly less maintainable to specify the ejb type everywhere. It is a very strict approach.

Answer (score -2):

If you dont specify any type in your dependency, it will select default type as "jar" which means look for a file with jar extension on any remote/local repository. When you specify any other type like "ejb", "so", "aar" maven will look for file with this extension.

Comment: At the moment I got type ejb but I can't find an artifact with file extension ".ejb" in my ear. There is only a "artifactId.jar".