# Dependency in Maven: What is the effect of type ejb?

Tags: java, maven, ejb

If you declare a dependency in Maven, you can add a type, like war, jar, ejb.

I understand that *compiling* a project with type ejb is different from compiling a project with type jar because it triggers a different lifecycle.

But what is the difference in declaring a dependency?

[Maven dependency type ejb vs jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427234/maven-dependency-type-ejb-vs-jar) seems to ask the same question, but the accepted answer seems strange to me. I doubt that a type in a dependency can trigger a lifecycle. Actually, I would expect that type ejb and type jar do exactly the same thing. Can somebody shed light on this?

Comment: Maybe more thoughts can be added, but yes, they should behave in exactly the same way, and only differ for "documentation" purposes ([peek at the source code of maven-aether-provider for example](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/maven-3.3.9/maven-aether-provider/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/repository/internal/MavenRepositorySystemUtils.java#L115-L116)). A different lifecycle is launched when you have a project with packaging EJB i.e. `<packaging>ejb</packaging>`, not a dependency on a EJB.

Comment: There is no accepted answer in your linked topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I doubt that a type in a dependency can trigger a lifecycle

You are not alone to doubt.

When you declare a dependency with the `ejb` type, you benefit from some facilities provided by Maven related to `ejb` as :

- the ability to add the declaration of the EJB in the `application.xml`.
  Since Java EE 5, it is not required any longer.
- the check that the dependency is a EJB and not a simple JAR.
- and probably some other minor things.

You would have not these facilities if you declare your dependency with the jar `type`.

As you can notice, it doesn't change at a lot of thing but anyway, in both cases, it is the same JAR which is used for the dependency.

You don't refer to the `ejb-client` type but it is often something of more interesting since contrary to the case of the dependency with the `jar` or `ejb` type which uses the same jar, when you declare `ejb-client` type in a dependency, you depend on a different jar that the classic jar since this jar should contain only API classes to call the `ejb`.
Of course, if we want the version `ejb-client` of our `ejb`, we have to specify it in the artifact which produces the `ejb`.

Comment: In JBoss EAP 7 I noticed that packaging type ejb may be needed for dependency injection. JBoss could not find an EJB (ie Singleton) in a jar packaged module (or external jar dependency). It required package-ejb and dependency type ejb for that to work.